# Url query string send by sone other web application

Tags: javascript, php

One company with .net web application is asking for any page url of my php application, so that they can attach some sort of query string to it. So suppose the page url which I gave him is abc.com and after he attached query, it becomes abc.com?regis=1233

My question is how to fetch that querystring at my end as it will keep on changing.

Comment: you mean `$_GET['regis];` ??.. Make sure that variable is sanitized as we do not even know what its for

Comment: `it will keep on changing.` change what, the key or the value?

Answer (score 0):

All the `GET` and `REQUEST` variables are put into a superglobal array: `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST`. You can access the value of `Query String` with `$_GET['regis']` or `$_REQUEST['regis']`.
[For Detail Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple ,you can use $_GET

for example

```
//get all the params
$request = $_GET;

//print the request
var_dump($request);

//iterate the request to get the request params
foreach ($request as $params_name => $value) {
    echo $params_name." => " .$value;
}
```